# How to Return updated store from Extjs grid to a grails controller

Tags: grails, extjs4

```
i am sending a ListofMap say 'ListofCSVMap' from my Grails(2.2.4) controller to Extjs (4.2.1) store 

Like this 

                            csvMap.put('Code', code)
                            csvMap.put('Number', number)
                            csvMap.put('Country', country)
                            listOfCsvMap.add(csvMap)

                            session.setAttribute("rows", listOfCsvMap)
                             render([items:listOfCsvMap] as JSON)

Now in my Extjs grid panel i am using the above listofCsvMap like this in my extjs store 
var store1;
Ext.onReady(function() {
      document.getElementById('legendId').style.display = "none";
         store1 = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        storeId: 'myStore1',
        pageSize: 20,
        proxy: {
             type: 'ajax',
             url:'loadGrid',
              reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'items'
              }  

        },
        fields: ['Code','Number','Country']

    }); 




 i am editing a country using Roweditor Plugin like this 


                     {
                    text : '<b>' + 'Country Of Origin' + '</b>',
                    //locked   : true,
                    width : 110,
                    sortable : false,

                    dataIndex : 'Country',
                    editor : { 
                        // for editable field, set a proper field xtype for it
                        xtype : 'combobox',
                        queryMode : 'remote',
                        editable : true,
                        id: 'countryDrop',
                        displayField : 'countryName',
                        valueField : 'countryName',
                        allowBlank : false,
                        store : new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                            proxy: {
                                type: 'ajax',
                                url: 'loadCountry',
                                reader: {
                                    type: 'json'
                                }
                            },
                            autoLoad: true,
                            fields: [
                                {type: 'string', name: 'countryName'}
                            ]
                        })
                    }
```

My requirement is when user edits the country field which is a combobox  in the Extjs grid panel i want to return the entire updated Extjs store to my Grails Controller and update the listOfCsvMap which i am storing in session or is it possible to update the session attribute  within the extjs grid it self after editing

Please help me with this !

Comment: i want to store the updated store as a Listof map just like the one i use to populate the extjs store

Comment: Please be more carefull in formatting your question. It's very hard to read and understand your question.

Comment: i have updated my question with code snippets

Comment: your snippet is mixed with your comments. Also, remove redundant indentation.

Comment: How can I correct it??